# c++ read txt file and copy into two classes istream::peek()

Tags: c++, fstream, istream, peek

```
istream& operator>>(istream& s, vector<Order>& ord) {

    string c{};
    bool got_customer = false;
    Customer temp_customer{};
    vector<Purchase>vec_purchase{};
    while (s >> c) {
        cout << "Erstes Wort der Zeile: "<<c << endl;

        if (!got_customer) { //c[0] == '#'
            c.erase(c.begin()); //löscht erstes Element vom string
            int k_nummer{};
            string k_vname{};
            string k_nname{};
            string k_plz{};
            string k_stadt{};
            k_nummer = stoi(c); //string to int
            s >> k_vname >> k_nname >> k_plz>>k_stadt;
            k_vname += " " + k_nname;
            temp_customer = Customer(k_nummer, k_vname, k_plz, k_stadt);
            got_customer = true;
        } else {
            string p_name{};
            double p_preis{};
            int p_menge{};
            p_name = c;
            s >> p_preis>>p_menge;
            cout << p_name << "  " << p_preis << "  " << p_menge << endl;
            vec_purchase.push_back(Purchase{p_name, p_preis, p_menge});
        }

        cout<<s.peek()<<endl;
        if (s.peek() == '#') {
            ord.push_back(Order{temp_customer, vec_purchase});
            temp_customer = Customer{};
            vec_purchase.clear();
            got_customer = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the txt file:

```
#725454 Schenker Rudolf DE-30159 Hannover
Shirt 135.95 1
Tie 89.59 1
#987654 Orbison Roy US-TN37075 Hendersonville
Mug 1.49 3
T-Shirt 14.90 1
#123456 Petty Tom US-FL32641 Gainesville
Flashlight 12.95 2
#246802 Hite Bob US-CA90291 Venice
CannedBeans 0.89 10
CannedTomatoes 1.79 6
#246802 Hite Bob US-CA90291 Venice
CanOpener 0.48 1
Spoon 1.49 4
Needle 0.05 100
```

The lines starting with '#' are Customer objects.
The other lines are Purchase objects.

I'm trying to peek into the upcoming char but im getting the same char again and again. In this case i always get '13' as output of s.peek().

€dit:
Thank you @Mark Ransom. 
Here is the working code if anybody has the same problem. :)

```
istream& operator>>(istream& s, vector<Order>& ord) {
    string c{};
    bool got_customer = false;
    Customer temp_customer{};
    vector<Purchase>vec_purchase{};

    while (s >> c) {
        if (!got_customer) { 
            c.erase(c.begin()); //deletes first char of string
            int k_nummer{};
            string k_vname{};
            string k_nname{};
            string k_plz{};
            string k_stadt{};
            k_nummer = stoi(c); //string to int
            s >> k_vname >> k_nname >> k_plz>>k_stadt>>ws;
            k_vname += " " + k_nname;
            temp_customer = Customer(k_nummer, k_vname, k_plz, k_stadt);
            got_customer = true;
        } else {
            string p_name{};
            double p_preis{};
            int p_menge{};
            p_name = c;
            s >> p_preis>>p_menge>>ws;
            vec_purchase.push_back(Purchase{p_name, p_preis, p_menge});
        }

        if (s.peek() == 35||s.peek() == -1 ) {  //35 (in ascii) -> # , -1 -> end of txt file
            ord.push_back(Order{temp_customer, vec_purchase});
            temp_customer = Customer{};
            vec_purchase.clear();
            got_customer = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you read from a stream, the input will stop on the first whitespace character. The character with a decimal code of 13 is the [ASCII CR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return), which comes at the end of every line in Windows; it is considered whitespace. You need to skip the whitespace to find the next *significant* character. You do this with [`std::ws`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws).

```
s >> k_vname >> k_nname >> k_plz >> k_stadt >> std::ws;

s >> p_preis >> p_menge >> std::ws;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 s >> p_preis>>p_menge;
```

This is intended to read the last two fields on a line with a record. Immediately afterwards:

```
 if (s.peek() == '#') {
```

Your obvious intent here is to peek at the first character on the next line, to check if the next line starts with `#`, or not.

Well, this is not going to happen, like that...

The problem is that the `>>` operator does not consume the end of line character after the processed input. `peek()` here is going to get you the newline character, instead. Surprise.

Given a sample input line:

```
 Tie 89.59 1
```

The "1" part will be read by `>>p_menge`, and stored into `menge`. The next character after `1` will be the newline character, and that's what `peek()` will happily give you.

This is completely the wrong approach for this task. There's only one correct approach to read files containing lines of text:

`std::getline()`

That's it. `std::getline()`, and nothing else. Learn how to use it. I'll make your life much simpler.

You can certainly use the `>>` operator to read lines from your input file, piecemeal, one field at a time, but as you've discovered this is an error-prone and fragile process. Too many minefields and pitfalls.

Well, of course, it's possible to do this right using the `>>` operator, but it's not always obvious how to do it, and one needs to fully understand all the nuances of formatted input operations.

It's unfortunate that too many introductory C++ books begin right off the bat presenting examples that use the `>>` operator to read input consisting of lines of text. This only confuses most beginners, and leads to problems, and misunderstandings, like these.

You need to rewrite your program to use `std::getline()` to read one line of text at a time. End of story.

Once you've read the whole line of text into a `std::string`, and checked whether or not it starts off with the `#` character: if you feel like it ***then*** you can stuff the whole line into a `std::istringstream`, and then use the `>>` operator, in a controlled environment.

Comment: While I agree that `getline` will make life easier, I can't condone this attitude of it being the *only* answer.

Comment: Hi thank you so much for answering :)
Of course i know about std::getline but I have to work with istream_iterators its a school project

Comment: `>>` is not an istream iterator. Furthermore, if you reread the last paragraph in my answer slowly, I explained how you can use it correctly.